# Verifying piecewise function is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x) =  |x|^{-a}$ if $|x| \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Prove that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R^d}$ if and only if $a$ < $d$.

going to need some help with this one, this Lebesgue integration stuff is so hard! If anyone can lend me some insight that'd be awesome.

So i'm thinking I'll have to do something with expressing f as the limit of a series of simple functions? I have so much experience calculating Riemann integrals, but haven't the slightest clue on how to work with Lebesgue integrals, so my first instinct is to go back to how we constructed them, but I can't help but get the feeling that this is unnecessary.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your post with what you've tried.

Comment: Try using n-dimensional polar coordinates. This is fine since |x|^(-a) is regular enough for 0<|x|<1. This should tell you that if a is too large, the integral blows up. You shouldn't worry about the jump at |x|=1 since the set {x:|x|=1} has Lebesgue measure zero. The main point of this problem is really the Behavoir of |x|^(-a) near x=0. It is instructive to see what happens in the one dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that

$$\int_{|x|<1} |x|^{-a}\,dm_d(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2^{-n-1}<|x|<2^{-n}} |x|^{-a}\,dm_d(x) $$

You can make the simplest estimates possible on the terms of the sum to solve the problem.

Comment: so as $2^{-n}$ approaches zero, $(1/2^{n})^{-a}$ will approach $\infty$. But this limit that approaches $\infty$ will be multiplied by the a set whose measure approaches zero, yet apparently the integral will still diverge to $\infty$. Is this correct? Can you help me fill in the details?

Comment: For the integrals on the right, $|x|^{-a}$ is like $2^{an}$ while $m_d(\{2^{-n-1}<|x|<2^{-n}\})$ is a constant times $2^{-nd}.$

Comment: Why does the measure equal a constant times $2^{-nd}$?

Comment: Because the volume of a ball of radius $r$ is a constant times $r^d.$